# How to use django-filter with a ListView class view for search?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a filter:

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

and a ListView to see the results:

```
class SearchResultsListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'book/search_results.html'
```

I want to have a search form where you can filter based on all fields of a class (ex, all books written by X with more than 3 stars).

How do I pass the form to the model, and how do I use the get request to filter with django-filter as needed?

I'm using Django 3.0 and django-filter 2.2.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think everything is well documented in the [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/) documentation under [**Generic view & configuration**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration) section. 
The **`django_filters.views.FilterView`** class is similar to Django's **`ListView`** and you can use it to filter the results.

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView


class SearchResultsListView(FilterView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'book/search_results.html'
    filterset_class = BookFilter # ADD YOUR filterset class
```

and do some change in your **`book/search_results.html`** template as [mentioned in here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-template),

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
        {{ obj.name }} - ${{ obj.price }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

### Key Points

1. Update **`SearchResultsListView`** class by inheriting **`FilterView`** class
2. Add **`filterset_class`** attribute to your **`SearchResultsListView`** view class
3. The **`FilterView`** class automatically adding the **`filterset_class`** class in the **`get_context_data(...)`** method to **`filter`** key, which can be accessible later in the template.
4. Use **`filter.qs`** in your template to get ***filtered queryset***

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed a full example. Just to make sure, I don't need a csrf_token in the form?

Comment: `csrf_token` is something to do with ***HTTP POST*** requests and the filter usually works with ***HTTP GET***. So, in your case, we don't need it

Comment: Thanks for the addditional Key Points, very useful!

Comment: One can also lookup the template using the ```book_list``` as it is declared as context_object_name. In this case you don't have to refactor your template with ```filter.qs```.  It is better to user ```filter.form``` for rendering the filtering form and ```book_list``` to render the data.