# FIlter Class Based View ListView that has pagination

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do a ListView from a Class Based View that has filtering, and pagination

I was able to get the table showing and the pagination working as I want, this gives me a basic list of all invoices that I need to show:

[image]

but I'm not able to make the filtering work, for what I understand I need to override the "get_queryset" method and this would return a queryset, (in this cased called "invoices_filtered_list") however I don't know how should I render this in the .html page so it will have the textbox in which I should type.

These are my files:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView, ListView)
from .models import WoodhistAzolveInvoices
from .filters import WoodhistAzolveInvoicesFilter


class InvoicesListView(ListView):
    model = WoodhistAzolveInvoices
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'invoices'
    ordering = ['suppliername', 'invoicenumber']
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        invoices_filtered_list = WoodhistAzolveInvoicesFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return invoices_filtered_list.qs
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import InvoicesListView

app_name = 'web'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', InvoicesListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters
from .models import *

class WoodhistAzolveInvoicesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = WoodhistAzolveInvoices
        fields = ['suppliername']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class WoodhistAzolveInvoices(models.Model):
    docid = models.CharField(db_column='DocId', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supplierreference = models.CharField(db_column='SupplierReference', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    suppliername = models.CharField(db_column='SupplierName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    invoicenumber = models.CharField(db_column='InvoiceNumber', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'WoodHist_Azolve_Invoices'
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} base title {% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<h1> azolve home </h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <form method="get">
        {{ invoices_filtered_list.form }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<table id="myTable1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Supplier Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Invoice Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Reference</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for datarow in invoices %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{datarow.suppliername}}</td>
    <td>{{datarow.invoicenumber}}</td>
    <td>{{datarow.supplierreference}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {% if is_paginated %}
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page=1">First</a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

  {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == num %}
      <a class="btn btn-info" href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a>
    {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
    {% endif %}

  {% endif %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

If it worth noting, I'm using the package "django_filters" and Django 3.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want filtering and pagination at the same time.

you need to make your pagination to keep your `querystrings` then you can have them at the same time. Because when you click on next page your **querystring** will be like this `.../?page=page_number` so your filtering will be gone.

you can do this:

1. Inside your app directory create a folder called `templatetags`.
2. Inside the templatetags folder create a file called `pagination_tags.py`(name is up to you).

   ```
   # Your template tag in app_name/templatetags/pagination_tags.py
   from django import template
   from urllib.parse import urlencode


   register = template.Library()

   @register.simple_tag
   def url_replace (request, field, value):
       dict_ = request.GET.copy()
       dict_[field] = value

       return dict_.urlencode()
   ```
3. After creating your template tag load it in your html page and use it.

   ```
   {% load pagination_tags %}

   {% if is_paginated %}
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation example" class="d-flex justify-content-center pt-3">
     <ul class="pagination">
       {% if page_obj.has_previous and page_obj.number != 2 %}
       <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-dark" href="?{% url_replace request 'page' 1 %}" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">First Page</a></li>
       {% endif %}
       {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
       <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-dark" href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.previous_page_number %}">{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}</a></li>
       {% endif %}
       <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{ page_obj.number }}</a></li>
       {% if page_obj.has_next %}
       <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-dark" href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.next_page_number %}">{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}</a></li>
       {% endif %}
       {% if page_obj.paginator.num_pages != page_obj.number and page_obj.paginator.num_pages != page_obj.next_page_number %}
       <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link text-dark" href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.paginator.num_pages %}">Last Page</a></li>
       {% endif %}
     </ul>
   </nav>
   {% endif %}
   ```
4. And your `ListView` should be replaced by `FilterView`

   ```
   from django_filters.views import FilterView
   from .models import WoodhistAzolveInvoices
   from .filters import WoodhistAzolveInvoicesFilter


   class InvoicesListView(FilterView):
       model = WoodhistAzolveInvoices
       template_name = "home.html"
       filterset_class = WoodhistAzolveInvoicesFilter
       context_object_name = 'invoices'
       ordering = ['suppliername', 'invoicenumber']
       paginate_by = 50
   ```

Comment: this would work for the pagination, but what about filtering? I wasn't able to get filtering work :(  pagination was working before

Comment: you couldn't filter at all? what's the problem ? is it necessary to use `django-filter` for filtering ? @Baldie47

Comment: your form obj will be `filter` now in templates by doing this

Comment: and how does the searchbox appears? I'm missing that part. how do I have the box where to type what I want the list to be filtered by?

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480402/how-to-use-django-filter-with-a-listview-class-view-for-search) @Baldie47

Comment: yes, this was the solution, I mean, this in combination to your text. I still can't entirely wrap my head around how it works, (I'm learning django) but thank you :) this solved my problem